# How to add href text tag to dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I add `'abc_xyz'` to a list?  Also, in adjacent columns, I want to add some numbers, which are metrics for failures and success of tasks that have run.  Here is a screen shot.

How can I achieve this?  I think building a list and then converting everything to a data frame is the way to go with this, right.

Comment: you cant - dictionary consist of `key:value` pairs. You can not add a "keyonly" thing to a dict.

Comment: As @PatrickArtner said.. Maybe dictionary won't work for you, try list or some other object to hold your data

Comment: Or give it a key of `href` which'd make sense... Although I suspect the real question here is actually - how can I reference the text of the object whose attributes I'm iterating over as a key in my dictionary... (or something like that).

Comment: I just updated my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a JSON object.